# Where is it said that the Witch-King had a fire-sword?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

It is seen in the movie that the witch-king has a sword that turns into flame. I was wondering if this appears in the book.

This scene is an Extended Scene in RotK and most of the Extended scenes don't happen in the books. Where in the books is he said to wield such a sword and how many times did he wield it?

Comment: But, but, the films are nonsense ...

Comment: Most of the extended scenes do happen in the books. That is the main reason why they were filmed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is mentioned in the chapter 'Siege of Gondor' in *The Return of the King*.

From the book;

> The Black Rider flung back his hood, and behold! he had a kingly crown; and yet upon no head visible was it set. The red fires shone between it and the mantled shoulders vast and dark. From a mouth unseen there came a deadly laughter. "Old fool!" he said. "Old fool! This is my hour. Do you not know Death when you see it? Die now and curse in vain!" **And with that he lifted high his sword and flames ran down the blade.**

He only wields it **once** as shown in the books. He swapped it for a giant mace during his battle with Eowyn.

> He bent over her like a cloud, and his eyes glittered; he raised his mace to kill.

Comment: "Hmmm, awesome flame sword.... or complicated unwieldy metal blob on a stick? Unwieldy metal blob." - Witch-King of Angmar, shortly after kicking Istari and Gondorian butt with awesome flame sword and shortly before dying to an inexperienced princess and a hobbit.

Comment: Actually, nothing makes a statement "Screw every bone in your body and your armor too" as big, heavy, spiked blob of metal.

Comment: Remember that a sword is an unwieldy metal stick.

Comment: This also happened in the Rankin–Bass version, believe it or not.

Comment: The Rankin-Bass cartoons, although the have a lot of cuts, were clearly made by people who admired the source material, and they preserve many minor but evocative details like this.